# How much salt, add to tap water to purge bivalvia?

Tags: mussels

I live Toronto, and our tap water is fresh water, not salty. I talk for each LB of bivalvia like clams mussels.

1. How much tap water?
2. How much salt to add?
3. What g of salt per LB NEVER to outstrip? What concentration kills them?

For pics, pls see [After purge mussels 6 time in salt water 20 mins each, why they still exude much grime?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/104957/67768/)

Comment: To ensure you *never* kill them, you would need to replicate the water they lived in before they were caught. Ocean salinity varies depending on location.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate seawater, you need [35g per 965g](https://sciencing.com/make-sea-water-home-6368912.html) (more or less 1 liter)  of fresh water.